# Unable to find Applications folder in Mac's terminal

Tags: macos, find, locate

I tried the following code unsuccessfully

```
find Applications | xargs -0 grep Applications
```

I also tried the following unsuccessfully

```
find Applications
```

Comment: Your first command is nonsense. First, you need to use `find -0' and `xargs -0' together, not mix-and match. Second, `find' prints lines - you don't need `xargs'. Third, the `grep' is pointless because every filename `find' prints will contain "Applications".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was it something instead like:

```
mdfind Applications | grep Applications
```

`mdfind` is a command line interface to *Spotlight*.  Somehow, I doubt this is what you were looking for.

The following command will find the names of Mac apps you have installed somewhere under `/Applications`.

```
find /Applications -type d -name "*.app"
```

Your question as phrased is pretty hard to help with, since you are not stating what your overall intent is...

Comment: Do you know which software Google Desktop use? Perhaps, mdfind?

Comment: I think Google Desktop on the Mac does some of its own indicing (independent of Apple's Spotlight)  See: http://desktop.google.com/support/mac/bin/answer.py?answer=59980&topic=10855

Answer (score 3):

It's in /Applications.

Try

```
find /Applications
```

Comment: That recursively lists everything in the Applications directory, which isn't terribly useful for most purposes.